# How to build our custom chromium based lightweight browser with does not require installation to launch

Tags: python, java, visual-c++, chromium, chromium-embedded

I need to create a browser which is chromium based and do not require any kind of dependencies or installation to launch, and **do not allow** browser specific functionalities like reloading, open in new tab, back and next button, developer tools and also want to hide the address bar.

While looking out for options we have already tried JavaFx web view with JxBrowser, it serves the purpose, but firstly it is dependent on Java and also the size of JRE files is about 170 MB which is large for our requirements, so was looking out for option for which size should be less than 50 MB.

So, please let know what would be best approach for creating this browser.

Answer (score 0):

With jlink and jpackage you can reduce the size of the Java solution.